# how to limit possible input while using raw_input? (also using split)

Tags: python, string, split, int

i want to limit the users input in two cases:

1.With a string and split, when asking the user to put in two, 2 digit numbers I wrote:

```
x=raw_input("words").split()
```

I want to only enable him to write an input that is two 2 digit numbers, and if he does something else I want to pop an error, and for him to be prompted again, until done right.

2.This time an INT when asking the user for a random 4 digit number:

```
y=int(raw_input("words"))
```

I only want to allow (for example) 4 digit numbers, and again if he inputs `53934` for example I want to be able to write an error explaining he must only enter a 4 digit number, and loop it back until he gets it right.

## Thank you, hopefully I explained myself properly.

update
so - trying to start simple i decided that at first ill only try to ask the user to type in 8 letters. for example an `qwertyui` input is acceptable, but `sadiuso` (7 chars) is not.

so i tried working with the syntax you gave me and wrote:

```
y=raw_input("words") if not (len(y) == 8):
    pop an error
```

but im getting a syntax error on the `:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`str.isdigit`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) and [`len`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len)

```
>>> '12345'.isdigit()
True
>>> 'ab12'.isdigit()
False
>>> len('12')
2
```

---

```
while True:
    x = raw_input('Input 2 digits: ')
    if x.isdigit() and len(x) == 2:
        x = int(x)
        break
    print('input should be 2 digits.')

print('x = {}'.format(x))
```

Comment: ok i need a LITTLE more help here, even though this is a huge step in the right direction, would you mind showing me how exactly to input that into my code? still very new to this.

Comment: @Giladiald, Put `if` statement after the `raw_input` line.

Comment: @falsetru, why use an if instead of an assert? I'm under the impression assert is more Pythonic by asking for forgiveness later..

Comment: @Leifingson, See  https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2013-November/660401.html

Comment: @falsetru, thanks, I had my suspicions about using assert which is why I asked, but how about a try-except? Maybe performance wise it'd be better to assume a correct input and catch a bad one..

Comment: @Leifingson, I also prefer `try: int(..) except ValueError: ...` when I check the input is `int`-able. But OP also want to check the length of the input....

Comment: ok i updated the question with my attempt... maybe someone will be able to explain waht im doing wrong.

Comment: @Giladiald, You should put `if` statement in separated line, not at the same line with `raw_input`.

Comment: @Giladiald, BTW `pop an error` is not an actual code. Replace it with the code that pop an error. something like `print('Input should be 2 digits')`

Comment: ok but what if i don't want an error? i want the user to need to re-type the input untill he gets it right